# How to design a GUI in Visual C# 2013 or Qt as shown in below figure

Tags: c#, qt, user-interface

I would like to design a Gui like this:

[image]

I tried to make a graph with X,-X,Y,-Y axis but it was not as expected. The origin(0,0) should be in the middle. I would like to add the objects(A1,A2,A3,A4) on my graph with different positions as shown. T is a movable object and it should be able to display its position as point T(x,y). The graph scale should be in meters.

Have to add a "danger" range with the radius of 15 meters from the origin. Have to add a "Warning" range with the radius of 25 meters from the origin. More than 25 meters would be a safe zone. How to make it with drag and drop in Visual c# or with the code.

I am pretty new to visual c# GUI development.

Comment: Questions asking for suggestions and directions on how to achieve something usually are not very welcome here (I think there are exceptions). It'd be better if you shared your code, with what you have already tried so far, and what's going wrong, so people would be able to help fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this with the controls that WinForms (If that's what you're planning to use) gives you.
Your best bet is to create a custom control and you can do all of that.

It's not gonna be easy, but it's probably your only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this code will get you started.

Create a Windows Forms Application and add a new form named "RadarForm".  Add two buttons to the form.  Clicking one button will add a random blip and clicking the other button will clear all the blips.

This code resets the origin for the form to be at its center and all x, y coordinates are based on that.

One button adds a random `RadarBlip` to the form, it has a 50/50 chance of being an "enemy".  Friendly blips are drawn in Blue and enemy blips are drawn in Red.

For Windows Forms, all drawing should be done in the `OnPaint` override method.

```
public partial class RadarForm : Form
{

    //A List to hold our blips
    private List<RadarBlip> blips = new List<RadarBlip>();

    //Random number generator
    private Random random = new Random();

    public RadarForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Setting to prevent flickering when redrawing the graphics
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);

    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        //Set the graphics quality to high quality
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        //Set the origin of the Cartesian plane to the center of the form
        resetOrigin(e.Graphics);

        //draw "danger" circle.  This would be your 15 meter circle
        drawCircle(new Point(0, 0), 200, 3, Color.Red, e.Graphics);

        //Draw X and Y Axes
        using (var p = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 3.0F))
        {
            //Draw X axis
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(-Width / 2, 0), new Point(Width / 2, 0));
            //Draw Y axis
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, -Height / 2), new Point(0, Height / 2));
        }

        //Draw all the radar blips in the collection  red = enemy blue = friendly.  
        //Each blip is drawn 10 pixels in size.
        foreach (var blip in blips)
        {
            Brush b = blip.IsEnemy ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Blue;
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, blip.X - 5, blip.Y - 5, 10, 10);
        }
    }

    //Create a random radar blip.  50/50 chance of being an enemy
    private RadarBlip createRandomBlip()
    {
        return new RadarBlip
        {
            X = random.Next(-Width / 2, Width / 2 + 1),
            Y = random.Next(-Height / 2, Height / 2 + 1),
            IsEnemy = random.Next(0, 101) > 50
        };
    }

    private void resetOrigin(Graphics g)
    {
        // Flip the Y-Axis so that positive values are upward on the axis
        g.ScaleTransform(1.0F, -1.0F);

        // Translate the drawing area accordingly so the origin is in the center of the form
        g.TranslateTransform(Width / 2.0F, -Height / 2.0F);
    }

    private void drawCircle(Point center, int radius, int thickness, Color color, Graphics g)
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle(center.X - radius, center.Y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
        using (var p = new Pen(color, thickness))
        {
            g.DrawEllipse(p, rect);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        blips.Add(createRandomBlip());
        this.Refresh();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        blips.Clear();
        this.Refresh();
    }
}

public class RadarBlip
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnemy { get; set; }
}
```